# manipulation of columns in a list

Tags: python, list

I'd like to iterate through columns of this sudoku, and replace all 0 with a list of number not attributed. Is there a way to simply iterate through all elements of the 1st column ?

Right now i was thinking of making a list, append all 1st item of everylist. It doesn't look really convenient to me...

```
sudoku = [
[0,5,0,8,0,6,7,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,9,5,0,0],
[2,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,3],
[0,4,0,0,2,0,0,5,5],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[7,2,0,0,9,0,0,4,0],
[4,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,7],
[0,0,7,9,0,0,2,0,0],
[0,0,5,3,0,2,0,6,0],
]
```

Edit :

My suboptimal workaround so far:

```
for a in range(9):
        column=[]
        for b in range(9):
            column.append(board[b][a])
        column=[x if x!=0 else [z for z in range(1,10) if z not in column] for x in column]
        for b in range(9):
            columns[b][a]=column[b]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Numpy you can simply iterate the transposed array:

```
for column in array.T:
   some_function(column)
```

Note that this operation is not memory expensive because it simply changes array strides.

*Reference: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "numbers not attributed", but you can use indexes to iterate through the list.

It sounds like you're only interested in the first element in the array. The following function checks the first element and replaces it with an empty list if it is 0:

```
sudoku = [
[0,5,0,8,0,6,7,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,9,5,0,0],
[2,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,3],
[0,4,0,0,2,0,0,5,5],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[7,2,0,0,9,0,0,4,0],
[4,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,7],
[0,0,7,9,0,0,2,0,0],
[0,0,5,3,0,2,0,6,0],
]

for col_index in range(0, len(sudoku)):
    if sudoku[col_index][0] == 0:
        sudoku[col_index][0] = []

for i in sudoku:
    print i
```

Output:

```
[[], 5, 0, 8, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0]
[[], 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3]
[[], 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 5]
[[], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
[[], 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
[[], 0, 5, 3, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0]
```

Comment: IE for the first line :
[0,5,0,8,0,6,7,0,0]
I'd like an output :
[[1,2,3,4,9], 5, [1,2,3,4,9], 8, [1,2,3,4,9], 6, [1,2,3,4,9], 7, [1,2,3,4,9], [1,2,3,4,9]]

And i want to do the same but with columns.